# How to get nearest vector in every cluster of faiss.IndexIVFFlat

Tags: vector, cluster-analysis, faiss, similarity-search

I'm using `faiss.IndexIVFFlat` with `nlist=10` to make an index of vectors I want to search. I have a query vector `xq` and I want to get the vector nearest to `xq` in each of the 10 clusters in the index. Is there a way to do this with faiss?

I see [here](https://gist.github.com/mdouze/b0a65aba70a64b00d6425b0e268a4c80) it is possible to get the contents of the inverted lists but doing this and querying is very slow. Is there a way to do this natively in `faiss`?